# Make all lower case and replace spaces with -

Tags: php

I am trying to generate some html pages and I have:

```
$category="Category Name";
$zone="Zone Name";
```

I am trying to get `$page="category-name-in-zone-name.html"`

Comment: Have you got any code so far? This is really not the place to ask other people to write code for you.

Comment: Look in the php docs at the [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [strtolower()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) functions

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the concept of 'slug creation':

```
function makeSlug($input)
{
    $interim = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $input);
    $interim = preg_replace("/[\"']+/i", '', $interim);
    $interim = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\\d]+/i", '-', $interim);
    return trim(strtolower($interim), ' -');
}
echo makeSlug("$category in $zone").'.html';
```

[Demo here](https://eval.in/206895).